# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\log(p_{n+1})}{\log(p_n)}\right)^n = C?$

Tags: limits, prime-numbers

There is a conjecture (which is weaker) related conjecture to Firoozbakht's conjecture (see OEIS A182514 Commments) which states (and define $L_n$): $$L_n := \left(\frac{\log(p_{n+1})}{\log(p_n)}\right)^n < e,$$ where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime.

This implies there might be constant, $C$, because as the RHS is constant as $n\to\infty$, and every thing on the LHS increasing without bound. So does $C$ exist and what value does it approach?

While I know that the $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\log(p_{n+1})}{\log(p_n)}\right) = 1$, and clearly $\left(\frac{\log(p_{n+1})}{\log(p_n)}\right) > 1$, it is the power, $n$, that is a curve-ball for me.

> Does the limit exist, and if it does, is the value $1,e$, or something
>   in between for: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} L_n = C?$$

Answer (score 4):

Based on what we believe to be true about primes, the limit in question doesn't exist; its lim inf is $1$ but its lim sup is greater than $1$, though probably finite. For simplicity we shall examine the logarithm of your expression,
$$
\log L_n = n \log \frac{\log p_{n+1}}{\log p_n}.
$$

Define a normalized gap between primes: $g_n = (p_{n+1}-p_n)/(\log p_n)^2$, so that $p_{n+1} = p_n + g_n \log^2 p_n = p_n (1+(g_n \log^2 p_n)/p_n)$. Then using $\log(1+x)=x+O(x^2)$ when $x=o(1)$, we have
\begin{align*}
n \log \frac{\log p_{n+1}}{\log p_n} &= n \log \frac{\log p_n +\log(1+(g_n \log^2 p_n)/p_n)}{\log p_n} \\
&= n \log \bigg( 1 + \frac{(g_n \log^2 p_n)/p_n + O((g_n \log^2 p_n)^2/p_n^2)}{\log p_n} \bigg) \\
&= n \bigg( \frac{g_n \log p_n}{p_n} + O\bigg( \frac{g_n^2 \log^3 p_n}{p_n^2} \bigg) \bigg).
\end{align*}
By the prime number theorem, $n = p_n/\log p_n+O(p_n/\log^2 p_n)$, so
\begin{align*}
n \log \frac{\log p_{n+1}}{\log p_n} &= \bigg( \frac{p_n}{\log p_n} + O\bigg( \frac{p_n}{\log^2 p_n} \bigg) \bigg) \bigg( \frac{g_n \log p_n}{p_n} + O\bigg( \frac{g_n^2 \log^3 p_n}{p_n^2} \bigg) \bigg) \\
&= g_n + O\bigg( \frac{g_n}{\log p_n} \bigg).
\end{align*}

If gaps between consecutive primes of size $x$ were $o(\log^2x)$ (which we currently cannot disprove), then $g_n$ would be $o(1)$ and hence $\log L_n$ would tend to $0$. Certainly the average gap is $\log x$, so $g_n\ll1/\log p_n$ must occur and the lim inf of $\log L_n$ equals $0$.

If gaps between consecutive primes of size $x$ were occasionally as large as $\Theta(\log^2x\log\log x)$ (which we also currently cannot disprove), then $g_n$ and hence $\log L_n$ would be unbounded above.

However, we believe that the maximal order of magnitude of prime gaps near $x$ is $\log^2x$. Therefore we believe that the lim inf of $g_n$ is positive and finite, which would say the same about $\log L_n$.

The actual lim sup of $g_n$ is a bit mysterious, but some now believe that its lim sup should equal $2e^\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. That would imply that $\limsup L_n = e^{2e^\gamma}$ and hence disprove  Firoozbakht's conjecture.

Comment: Because $p_{n+1} < 2p_n$, we see: $\log{p_{n+1}} < \log2 + \log{p_n}$, divide by $\log{p_n}$ and we have a upper bound for $L_n$. Take the $\log$ and you have an upper bounds to $\log L_n$

Comment: Also by the comment above: $\frac{\log{p_{n+1}}}{\log{p_n}} - 1 < \frac{\log{2}}{\log{p_n}}$.

Comment: But, relevance?

Comment: See your comment: "If gaps between consecutive primes ... then $g_n$ and hence $\log{L_n}$ would be unbounded above." This comment with proof of my comment proves this is not true, there is a bound above. While my statement is weak, it does its job. What is needed is finding the sharpest provable bound from above. Also this says, because $2 < e$ that the values $e < e^{2e^\gamma}$ is out of reach and $L_n$ is smaller than $e$.

Comment: As to the second comment. The left side is the same as $\frac{\log{p_{n+1}} - \log{p_n}}{\log{p_n}} < \frac{1}{n}$ which is a rewrite of the conjecture. So, something can be said between $\frac{1}{n}$ and  $\frac{\log{2}}{\log{p_n}}$.

Comment: Namely, if $\frac{\log{p_n}}{n} < \log{2}$ then the Firoozbakht conjecture still holds. Note that left side of this statement is the same the log of Firoozbakht conjecture: $p_n^{1/n}$ decreases for increasing $n$.

Comment: Your comment gives a bound for $\frac{\log p_{n+1}}{\log p_n}$, but that's not what $L_n$ is: it's $\big( \frac{\log p_{n+1}}{\log p_n} \big)^n$. I don't see any way to modify your argument to address the given problem fruitfully.

Comment: Another thought, Let $G_n = \frac{\log{p_{n+1}}}{\log{p_n}} - 1$. And, because $\log{(x + 1)} < x$,  we have $\log{(G_n+1)} = \log{\left(\frac{\log{p_{n+1}}}{\log{p_n}}\right)} < \frac{\log p_{n+1}}{\log p_n} - 1 = G_n$. This makes $\log L_n < n \left(\frac{\log p_{n+1}}{\log p_n} -1\right)$. So, if $\log L_n < 1$ then the Firoozbakht conjecture holds. Now because, $\frac{\log{p_{n+1}}}{\log{p_n}} - 1 < \frac{\log{2}}{\log{p_n}}$, so the assertion holds.

Comment: So if what I said above is true, then $L_n < e$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you keep dropping the $n$ in ways that make your arguments very wrong. You derived $\log L_n < n(\frac{\log p_{n+1}}{\log p_n}-1)$ and $\frac{\log p_{n+1}}{\log p_n}-1 < \frac{\log 2}{\log p_n}$; but together those give $\log L_n < n \frac{\log 2}{\log p_n}$ which tends to infinity quite quickly, yielding no information at all. - If you feel like my result is wrong, there must be some specific step I make that is false; what step is it?

Comment: $\frac{\log L_n}{n} = \log\left(\frac{\log p_{n+1}}{\log p_n}\right) < \frac{\log p_{n+1}}{\log p_n}-1 < \frac{1}{n} < \frac{\log{2}}{\log{p_n}} <1$, so $\log L_n = n \log \left(\frac{\log p_{n+1}}{\log p_n}\right) < n\left(\frac{\log p_{n+1}}{\log p_n}-1\right) < 1 < n\frac{\log{2}}{\log{p_n}} < n$.

Comment: Did that bring everything together and clear things up?

Answer (score 0):

Some extra notes.

$L_n := \left(\frac{\log(p_{n+1})}{\log(p_n)}\right)^n < e.$

$\frac{\log(p_{n+1})}{\log(p_n)} < e^{1/n},$ both sides approach 1.

$\frac{\log(p_{n+1})}{e^{1/n}\log(p_n)} = \frac{e^{-1/n}\log(p_{n+1})}{\log(p_n)} < 1,$ left side approaches 1.

Comment: A gp program and output:       ? n=1;p=2;lmt=0;forprime(q=3,10^9,lmt=(log(q)/log(p))^n;if(lmt>2.3,print(n," ",p," ",q," ",lmt));n++;p=q)
4 7 11 2.3058428918873513142502641716651094369

Comment: ? n=49749629143526;p=1693182318746371;lmt=0;forprime(q=1693182318746371+1132,1693182318746371+1132*2,lmt=(log(q)/log(p))^n;if(lmt>2.3,print(n," ",p," ",q," ",lmt));n++;p=q)
49749629143526 1693182318746371 1693182318747503 2.5819275433218254632348721804235156717
?